# Expected:: - Using Eclipse with PyDev

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x

I just started up the new version of python, and realized that a lot has changed. Anyways, eclipse comes up with a red "X" mark beside the line numbers saying "Expected::". Could someone please explain what this means, and how I can get rid of it?

This is the code I'm trying to make work with Eclipse and the new Python version:

```
print "Please insert a valid operator that you want to calculate with."

print "Valid operators are +, -, : and *"

operator = str(raw_input("What's your operator? "))

numb1 = int(raw_input("Please insert the first number:"))
numb2 = int(raw_input("Please insert the second number:"))

if operator == "+":
print numb1 + numb2
elif operator == "*":
print numb1 + numb2
elif operator == "-":
print numb1 - numb2
elif operator == "/":
print numb1 / numb2
```

Answer (score 1):

On Python3, `print` is a function, not a statement, so it should be written (for example)

```
print("Please insert a valid operator that you want to calculate with.")
```

Also `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` so it should be (for example):

```
numb1 = int(input("Please insert the first number:"))
```

Comment: But what about my actual question, expected::?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I don't use eclipse so I have no clue what that message is supposed to say or mean. I added the eclipse tag for you so hopefully someone there sees this and can answer you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this program and I saw no problems with it when I ran it on Pydev on Eclipse, even though I ran it on 2.7. perhaps it has something to do with your indentation.

```
operator = str(raw_input("What's your operator? "))

numb1 = int(raw_input("Please insert the first number:"))
numb2 = int(raw_input("Please insert the second number:"))

if operator == "+":
    print numb1 + numb2
elif operator == "*":
    print numb1 + numb2
elif operator == "-":
    print numb1 - numb2
elif operator == "/":
    print numb1 / numb2
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your example as well and to fix it I just had to fix the indentation as StackXchangeT did.

However I got `Expected::` error when there was missing finishing `:` at the end of declaration e.g.:

```
class MyInvalidClass
```

which is supposed to be:

```
class MyInvalidClass:
```

Perhaps you get such error in similar situations where `:` is needed (just a guess).